# Nature RemoのローカルAPIをswiftで使用したい。しかしステータスコード400が表示される。

Tags: swift, api

Nature RemoのローカルAPIを使用したくてプログラムを書いてるのですが上手くいきません。
ネットの記事を参考にしつつ、URLリクエストを送るプログラムを書きました。MacのターミナルでAPIを使用することはできたので、それをswiftで使用できないかと奔走中です。

ターミナルでは以下の通り実行するとAPIを使用できます。
（AAAAAの部分はデバイスID、XXXは数字）
http通信用のATSも試してみましたが上手くいきません。

ステータスコードが400なのでリクエストの内容が悪いのでしょうか。
右も左もわからないほぼ初心者なので誰か教えていただけると嬉しいです。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
curl -X POST 'http://AAAAA/messages' -H 'X-Requested-With: curl' -H 'accept: application/json' -d '{"format":"us","freq”:BB,”data":[XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,・・・・・]}'
```

**Swiftのコード:**

```
import UIKit
    
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // create the url-request
        let url = URL(string: "http://XXXXXX/messages")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        //set the method
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //add the header
        request.setValue("X-Requested-With: curl", forHTTPHeaderField: "Expect")
        request.setValue("accept: application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // set the request-body(JSON)
        let json:[String:Any] = [
            "format":"us",
            "freq":"38",
            "data":[8918,4554,473,657,476,654,500,631,504,627,499,637,503,1739,530,590,481,1762,494,1741,499,1744,494,1738,509,614,522,1720,478,1762,500,639,469,1763,498,1738,471,655,478,661,506,1721,547,586,479,1765,470,1771,494,1738,472,665,466,1768,469,1767,553,574,476,1767,470,660,499,632,474,675,455,39790,553,199,329,192,204,189,174,226,171,227,184,205,251,198,170,195,174,197,171,199,147,196,194,199,171,198,197,171,168,252,189,233,161,208,172,200,170,192,200,197,170,200,169,2464,351
            ],
        ]
        
        //add the "json" as a top level ovject's fact
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        
        // use URLSessionDataTask
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil, let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                
                // HTTPヘッダの取得
                print("Content-Type: \(response.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] ?? "")")
                // HTTPステータスコード
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
                print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 元のご質問ではステータスコードが404となっていたのを400に書き換えられたようですが、元々400だったのでしょうか?それとも何かをしたら404が400に変わったのでしょうか?あなたのコードはcurlコマンドで送っているのとは明らかに異なるヘッダ情報を送っているので、400 Bad Requestになる可能性はあるだろうと思いますが、404が400に変わった理由がわからないと、あまり確実なことが言えません。

Answer (score 0):

記載がないので直接関係しているか不明ですが、Appleのアプリケーションはhttp通信に`ATS`というセキュリティ設定が必用で、`https://`な通信のみ許可され、`http://`な通信は不許可になっていると思います。
ソースコードを実行したときにデバッグエリアに`ATS`に関する警告が出ていないか確認して下さい。
これを回避するためにそのアプリケーションのプロジェクトファイルの、`Info.plist`に

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AAAAA/key>
            <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

のような記載が必用かと思いますが、この設定をされているでしょうか？
この例が間違っている可能性もあるので、詳しくは`ATS` `http`　`許可`等で調べて正しい値を設定することが必用です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Info.plistのApp Transport Security Settingsの下層にあるAllow Arbitary LoadsをYESにしているのですがこれではいけないのでしょうか。以前記事でATSが云々の記事をみてこのような設定を追加しました。

Comment: ちなみにこのAAAAAの部分は僕が載せているコードのAAAAAと同一と考えてよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: あと、非常に申し訳ないのですがステータスコードは400でした。すみません。なのでリクエストの内容が悪いのかもしれません。

Comment: Allow Arbitary Loadsだけで良いと思います。回答中のAAAAAは、curlのAAAAAまたはソースのXXXXXXで記述されているドメインです。また、X-Requested-With:の行は不要で、次の行も”accept: ”無しで`request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")`だけで良いと思います

Answer (score 0):

Чайка さんへのコメントに、「ステータスコードは400でした」と書かれているので、「元々400だった」と判断しました。

Nature Remoの現物はありませんので、ご質問・コメントの内容から考えての1つの可能性としか言えませんが、現在のあなたのSwiftコードは「APIを使用できます」と書かれたcurlが送信するヘッダとは異なるヘッダを送信していますので、まずはそこを修正してみてください。

curlで`-H 'X-Requested-With: curl'`と指定する場合、ヘッダフィールド名が`X-Requested-With`で、その値が`curl`です。

したがって、あなたのcurlコマンドに合わせたヘッダを送信するSwiftコードは以下のようになります。

```
        //add the header
        request.setValue("curl", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
```

こちらの手元で試すことができないので確実なことが言えなくて申し訳ありませんが、当然 Чайка さんの書かれたATS設定は正しいか、curlで指定した`http://AAAAA/messages`とSwiftコード中の`http://XXXXXX/messages`は本当に同じURLなのか(`AAAAA`と`XXXXXX`と使い分けられている点が気になります)などの点については、何度でも再チェックした上で試してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りにヘッダーの部分を変えたら上手くいきました！！！本当にありがとうございます！！　Чайка さんとOOPerさんという親切なお二方のおかげで無事成功させることができました。本当に感謝しています！

Comment: まだまだ初心者の僕ですが、暖かい二人のおかげでなんとか今後も頑張れそうです。お世話になりました！